# TSQL query for finding rows that match a set of properties

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have got the following simplified schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [file]
( 
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    uri NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_file PRIMARY KEY (id ASC) ON [PRIMARY] 
)

CREATE TABLE [property]
( 
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    name NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_property PRIMARY KEY (id ASC) ON [PRIMARY] 
)

CREATE TABLE [metadata]
( 
    fileid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    propertyid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    value NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_metadata PRIMARY KEY (fileid, propertyid ASC) ON [PRIMARY] 
)
```

Where `[fileid]` FKs to `[file].[id]` and `[propertyid]` FKs to `[property].[id]`. Assume that `[properyid]` is `CLUSTERED` and `[value]` is a `NON-CLUSTERED`.

I want to select all of the files that match a certain set of metadata; for example every file that has a property value pair of `size = 1 Kb` and `extension = 'txt'`.

The query that I've come up with, for example with three properties specified, is this:

```
SELECT [uri] FROM [file] WHERE [id] IN (
    SELECT a.[fileid] FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) [count], [fileid] FROM [metadata]
        WHERE ([propertyid] = '597ddddf-afd2-414f-9774-36f067038064' AND 
                [value] = N'moo') OR
              ([propertyid] = 'd83d12de-e4bc-4d18-be12-743504df3318' AND 
                [value] = N'foo') OR
              ([propertyid] = 'c00c3966-5034-4818-8567-abd660f37f15' AND 
                [value] = N'boo')
        GROUP BY [fileid]
    ) a
    WHERE a.[count] = 3
)
```

Can I do any better?

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: I think we support all versions back to 2003 including express.

Comment: afaik, there was 2000 and then 2005

Comment: I'm sure you are right, so I guess it is probably 2005+ that we need to support.

Comment: Whoa! Halt. You need to immediately stop and go back and read boks on database performance and design before you proceed with a design like this. You have created something that will never perform well (for a whole lot of reasons like using nvarchar (max) which can't be indexed for one and EAV tables for another) and will always be hard to query.

Comment: ... which is why I was asking the question :) This is the schema that I've been given to work with, and I've been told that the customer has demanded it be 'as quick and dirty as possible'. No word of a lie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
;WITH propertylist AS (
  SELECT propertyid = '597ddddf-afd2-414f-9774-36f067038064', value = N'moo' UNION ALL
  SELECT propertyid = 'd83d12de-e4bc-4d18-be12-743504df3318', value = N'foo' UNION ALL
  SELECT propertyid = 'c00c3966-5034-4818-8567-abd660f37f15', value = N'boo'
)
SELECT uri
FROM file
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT m.fileid
  FROM metadata m
    INNER JOIN propertylist p ON m.propertyid = p.propertyid AND m.value = p.value
  GROUP BY m.fileid
  HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM propertylist)
)
```

Comment: That's looks like it might work, generally I've seen this sort of problem solved by joining to the metadata table once for each property you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT 
   [uri] 
FROM 
   [file] 
WHERE 
   EXISTS(
        SELECT 
           NULL
        FROM 
           [metadata]
        WHERE 
              ([propertyid] = '597ddddf-afd2-414f-9774-36f067038064' AND 
                [value] = N'moo') OR
              ([propertyid] = 'd83d12de-e4bc-4d18-be12-743504df3318' AND 
                [value] = N'foo') OR
              ([propertyid] = 'c00c3966-5034-4818-8567-abd660f37f15' AND 
                [value] = N'boo') AND 
              [File].[id] = [metadata].[fileid]
        GROUP BY 
           [fileid]
        HAVING 
           COUNT(*) = 3
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm maybe missing something, but if you want that all 3 conditions are satisfied, why don't just use "AND" each time instead of counting the number of properties set? You will avoid a GROUPING that isn't necessary.

I'll write :

```
    SELECT [uri] FROM [file] 
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT [fileid] FROM [metadata]
           WHERE [propertyid] = '597ddddf-afd2-414f-9774-36f067038064'
             AND [value] = N'moo'
             AND [propertyid] = 'd83d12de-e4bc-4d18-be12-743504df3318' 
             AND [value] = N'foo'
             AND [propertyid] = 'c00c3966-5034-4818-8567-abd660f37f15'
             AND [value] = N'boo'
             AND [file].[id] = [metadata].[fileid])
```

Comment: I do the `count` because I need exactly three rows to exist in `metadata`; one for each key-value pair. The inner query returns all rows that match any of the key value pairs, the query outside it then says 'give me only the `fileid`s where all conditions are matched'. Your query asserts that there exists a single row in `metadata` where the `propertyid` and `value` each simultaneously has three different values, as such it will always return nothing. By the way three property-value pairs is arbitrary, it could be any number.